What's the difference between '[validation] TransactionAddedToMempool' and '[mempool] AcceptToMemoryPool' log messages when running debug=1?
Running bitcoin core 28.0 with debug=1. What is the difference between these two logging messages?
2024-12-18T20:27:39Z [validation] TransactionAddedToMempool:
2024-12-18T20:27:39Z [mempool] AcceptToMemoryPool:
It also seems like not every transaction that gets the TransactionAddedToMempool message gets a AcceptToMemoryPool message.
